# Cassandra connection exception on large transactions

Tags: java, docker, exception, cassandra

I am using a cassandra docker container with the java api (localhost:8888 mapped to the container's 9042 port), with an application that only reads data from the keyspace.
Problem is, on large transactions I am getting the below exceptions:

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:8888 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1] Connection has been closed))
All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:8888 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1] Connection has been closed))
```

I cannot find any more details in `var/log/cassandra/` in the docker container as to what causes the connection to break.

On smaller transactions, the connection works fine. Is there something I can edit on the cassandra configuration (e.g. in `/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml` ?) to allow for larger payloads)?

Comment: whats the large transaction? insert? select? what size?

Comment: It's a select. Size is just 4096 rows of text data from a table.

Comment: try with smaller fetch size? like 32 instead of all 4096 in a single payload (5000 is default)

Comment: Yeah, that's the workaround I am using for the time being.